# Flickering Windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in using WPF c#. When I click button to show new window and hide my current, I notice that the window Flickers. How can I prevent this to happen?

What I want to do is when I change window,  It's like i'm in the same window but different content since it every windows I have has the same Header.

This my code wherein when i click on some button, it will redirect to another window. My problem is that while directing to another page, it flickers. What I think is it was due by the window UI /  content.

```
    private void button_cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow  main = new MainWindow();
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

I've tried creating new window which contains two buttons only. And it didn't flicker.

Comment: Have you considered having just one window where you change the content of the window instead of creating a new window?

Comment: each window has it's own functionality. So I decided not to do that.. if possible all i want is to prevent my header from Flickering. If you know how, can you please tell me? Thank you so much

Comment: `Window`s in WPF projects *do not flicker* on their own. I can only assume that *you* have inadvertently made them flicker with some of your code. To prove this, start a new project and run it... you'll see that the `Window` does *not* flicker. Therefore, nobody here can help you because we cannot reproduce your problem. If you create a minimal, but complete and concise working code example that demonstrates your problem, then we can help you. However, until you do that, I deem that this question cannot be answered and so have voted to close it. I'll be happy to undo this if you provide code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have taken the wrong approach, instead of creating a new window and hiding the original you should simply swap out the view that is currently active inside the current window.

As you have not posted any code I have no idea what this would look like for you however should you be using MVVM you would simply bind a ContentControl to the view that you would like shown.

This becomes much easier when using a framework like Caliburn Micro that is there to support things like View Composition.

You have mentioned "each window has it's own functionality" which makes me think you are not following best practice for WPF... you should avoid placing any logic in your view code behind for exactly this reason, you are best off refactoring and placing this code in a view model.

**Update**

It is likely that you are running a long running process on the UI thread which means that the long running process will block the UI thread (the thread that also has to create your window) and that is probably what is causing your window to flicker.

To solve this, move any long running processes to a new thread (using Task Parallel Library) or Async / Await if you have that feature available to you in the version of .NET framework you are targeting.

Comment: Does the length of the code affect the performance of a system? I mean, for example, for each window I have hundreds/thousands lines of code, will it affect the transition of the windows?

Comment: Depends what the code is doing of course, but you are looking in the wrong areas... I write enterprise apps with millions of lines of code and the performance is fine. Absolutely no window flickering. You would be doing any long running processes on a thread other than the UI thread however.

Comment: Please see my update: You will need to post some code in order for someone to help you with it any further however. (Create a new question).